# Rescue rails app from server failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rescue

I have a rails app which is now hosted on dedicated server. Today something happened: app doesn't respond and I have no ssh access, restarting doesn't help and I am waiting for tech support to respond. But this is not a question, I just need this app to be online even if server fails. Which is the easiest option? Can I create second server on different hosting and serve from there in case of failure, if so, how to sync db and files? Application is not heavily loaded, I just need it to be available.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult problem to solve. There's no one proven way to make this happen, but in general you need "No Single Point of Failure"

There's an entire science devoted to reliability in web applications -- no way can you get that answered in a SO question.

You can take frequent backups of your database, store them on S3 (and/or somewhere else). You can then

1. have an image of your applications server at your host
2. spin it up when your server dies
3. restore the database
4. Have the new application server take over responsibility (easiest way: assume the old server's IP address)

Comment: Check out the "all time favorites" in the right sidebar: http://highscalability.com